# How to get frame of particular color in UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I have to find the `frame` of the colors in a `UIView` like in the image below:

[image]

In this image I want to find the `frame` of triangles and want to add a `UIControl` to it.

Can I achieve that?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i Like ur comment

Comment: What does this question have to do with the `iphone` device and the `iOS` operating system?

Comment: I have some  idea for an app

Comment: The `iphone` tag is reserved for issues relating to the `iphone` device not because you're developing an app for it. Same applies for the `iOS` tag.

Comment: Are you using UIImageView or custom drawing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class with two properties: shape, color and image and subclass `UIImageView` with a new property: `imageObject`. (I just figured `YBImageObject` is a horrible class name so please change that if you're planning on using this code)

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSArray *images = @[@{@"name": @"darkgreen-circle1", @"shape" : @"Circle",   @"color" : @"#8dc1b1"},
                    @{@"name": @"darkgreen-circle2", @"shape" : @"Circle",   @"color" : @"#8dc1b1"},
                    @{@"name": @"darkgreen-circle3", @"shape" : @"Circle",   @"color" : @"#8dc1b1"},
                    @{@"name": @"lightblue-square1", @"shape" : @"Square",   @"color" : @"#00c1f5"},
                    @{@"name": @"lightblue-square2", @"shape" : @"Square",   @"color" : @"#00c1f5"},
                    @{@"name": @"red-circle1",       @"shape" : @"Circle",   @"color" : @"#ff799a"},
                    @{@"name": @"yellow-triangle1",  @"shape" : @"Triangle", @"color" : @"#e3ff86"},
                    @{@"name": @"yellow-triangle2",  @"shape" : @"Triangle", @"color" : @"#e3ff86"}];


int i = 0;
for (NSDictionary *dictImage in images){
    YBImageObject *imageObject = [[YBImageObject alloc] init];
    [imageObject setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[dictImage objectForKey:@"name"]]];
    [imageObject setShape:[dictImage objectForKey:@"shape"]];
    [imageObject setColor:[dictImage objectForKey:@"color"]];

    // imageView.frame.origin.x = total width of previous images * a little margin
    YBImageView *imageView = [[YBImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 1.2, 100, imageObject.image.size.width, imageObject.image.size.height)];
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [imageView setImageObject:imageObject];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGestures:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    i += imageObject.image.size.width;
}
```

In `handleTapGestures:`:

```
- (void) handleTapGestures:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    YBImageView *imageView = (YBImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;

    NSLog(@"Shape: %@", imageView.imageObject.shape);
    NSLog(@"Color: %@", imageView.imageObject.color);
}
```

[Source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5lv3n37u6cx670w/ColorAndShapeSubclassing.zip)

Comment: @gtechtech Sure, will take some minutes. ;)